# Single OSGi bundle across multiple Cellar nodes

Tags: osgi, akka, karaf

One basic question regarding OSGi. Can a single OSGi bundle be distributed across multiple Cellar nodes ? Say if I have an OSGi bundle created with Actors (Akka) can I distribute the bundle across multiple nodes so that I can leverage further on the distributed actor functionality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know about what an Akka bundle else needs but if it is a self-contained bundle? Yes it is quite easy to distribute this bundle across multiple nodes within the same cluster-group. If you want some "exchange" mechanism between those distributed bundles you'll need to take care of this on your own, for example you might want to use the underlying Hazelcast to distribute a state throughout your clustered bundles.